# How to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k} x^k(1-x)^{n-k}}{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Apologies if I’ve just missed a duplicate, couldn’t find anything.

Have tried a few things but can’t seem to figure an obvious approach for a closed-form solution. This is just the standard expansion for k successes from N trials, but we weight each term by $1/k$

Comment: What is the term for $k=0$?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. Should start at $k=1$, have fixed now

Comment: Letting $$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom nkz^k}k,$$ then you are seeking $(1-x)^n f\left(\frac x{1-x}\right).$

Comment: Now, $f'(z)=\frac{(1+z)^n-1}{z}.$ But you likely won't find a good closed formula for the integral of. $f'.$

Comment: Do you consider hypergeometric function as a "closed-form solution"?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer gives a closed form for the coefficients of these polynomials.

If $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}}{k}$, then
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k+1}H_kx^k.$$
Where $H_k$ is the $k$th harmonic number.

\begin{align*}
P_n(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{r}(-1)^rx^{k+r}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{r=k}^{n}\binom{n-k}{r-k}(-1)^{r-k}x^r\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{r}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{r-k}(-1)^{r-k}x^r\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^nx^r\sum_{k=1}^{r}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{r-k}(-1)^{r-k}\\
\end{align*}
So the coefficient of $x^r$ in $P_n(x)$ is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{r}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{r-k}(-1)^{r-k}&=\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{(-1)^{r-k}}{k}\cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{(n-k)!}{(r-k)!(n-r)!}\\
&=\binom{n}{r}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\binom{r}{k}\\
&=\binom{n}{r}(-1)^{r+1}[z^r]\left\{\frac{1}{1-z}\log\left(1+\frac{z}{1-z}\right)\right\}\\
&=\binom{n}{r}(-1)^{r+1}[z^r]\left\{\frac{1}{1-z}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\right\}\\
&=\binom{n}{r}(-1)^{r+1}H_r.\\
\end{align*}

Comment: You don't need the generating function to prove what you want. Just expand $(1-x)^{n-k}$ and reorganize terms.

Comment: Apologies @Youem, I just brute forced it with the generating function but I have now updated my answer with the simplified derivation.